# How to convert Arraylist of objects to Javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, extjs, arraylist

Im using struts and javascript to show one table of elements, the method

```
public List<Object> preparaInformeRiesgoActivos( int dimension, String idTipoActivo, String idActivo, String tipoActivo, String nombreActivo, ResourceBundle recursos ) {
    // TO-DO: Cambiar query de else.
    String consulta = "";    
    if(dimension!=0){            
        consulta = "SELECT A.ID_AMENAZA, A.CODIGO, A.DENOMINACION, D.ID_RANGO, D.IMPACTO, D.RIESGO FROM (  SELECT ID_AMENAZA, ID_RANGO, SUM(IMPACTORESIDUAL) AS IMPACTO, SUM(RIESGORESIDUAL) AS RIESGO "
                +  "FROM AGR_IMP_RISK_REAL WHERE ID_TIPOACTIVO="+idTipoActivo+" AND ID_ACTIVO='"+idActivo+"' and ID_RANGO = 7 "
                +  "GROUP BY ID_AMENAZA, ID_RANGO) D , (  SELECT ID_AMENAZA, SUM(IMPACTORESIDUAL) AS IMPACTOTOTAL "
                +  "FROM AGR_IMP_RISK_REAL WHERE ID_TIPOACTIVO="+idTipoActivo+" AND ID_ACTIVO='"+idActivo+"'  and ID_RANGO = 7 "
                +  "GROUP BY ID_AMENAZA) T , AGR_AMENAZA A WHERE T.IMPACTOTOTAL<>0 AND T.ID_AMENAZA = D.ID_AMENAZA AND D.ID_AMENAZA = A.ID_AMENAZA ORDER BY D.ID_AMENAZA, D.ID_RANGO";
    }else{
        consulta = "SELECT A.ID_AMENAZA, A.CODIGO, A.DENOMINACION, D.ID_RANGO, D.IMPACTO, D.RIESGO FROM (  SELECT ID_AMENAZA, ID_RANGO, SUM(IMPACTORESIDUAL) AS IMPACTO, SUM(RIESGORESIDUAL) AS RIESGO "
                +  "FROM AGR_IMP_RISK_REAL WHERE ID_TIPOACTIVO="+idTipoActivo+" AND ID_ACTIVO='"+idActivo+"' and ID_RANGO = 7 "
                +  "GROUP BY ID_AMENAZA, ID_RANGO) D , (  SELECT ID_AMENAZA, SUM(IMPACTORESIDUAL) AS IMPACTOTOTAL "
                +  "FROM AGR_IMP_RISK_REAL WHERE ID_TIPOACTIVO="+idTipoActivo+" AND ID_ACTIVO='"+idActivo+"'  and ID_RANGO = 7 "
                +  "GROUP BY ID_AMENAZA) T , AGR_AMENAZA A WHERE T.IMPACTOTOTAL<>0 AND T.ID_AMENAZA = D.ID_AMENAZA AND D.ID_AMENAZA = A.ID_AMENAZA ORDER BY D.ID_AMENAZA, D.ID_RANGO";
    }
    Query q = dao.createNativeQuery(consulta);    
    List<Object> resultado = q.getResultList();    
    return resultado;
}
```

This method returns a collections of objects. in my jsp im using ExtJS as framework to show one table with this elements. How i can convert my java Arraylist in one javascript store without frameworks (if is it possible)?

```jsp
<%@page import="com.dominion.procop.agr.struts.forms.AGRInformesForm"%>
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function() {    
    var amenazaStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Amenazas',
        data: [
            { id: 1, codigo: 'E.1', denominacion: 'Errores de los usuarios', id_rango: '0', impacto: '0', riesgo: '0'},
            { id: 2, codigo: 'E.5', denominacion: 'Deficiencias en la organización', id_rango: '0', impacto: '0', riesgo: '0'},
            { id: 3, codigo: 'E.8', denominacion: 'Escapes de información', id_rango: '0', impacto: '0', riesgo: '0'},
            { id: 4, codigo: 'E.9', denominacion: 'Alteración accidental de la información', id_rango: '0', impacto: '0', riesgo: '0'}
        ]
    });

...
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can convert my java Arraylist in one javascript store without frameworks (if is it possible)?

Technically, it is possible. You will have to parse every object in your `List<Object> resultado` to a format that JavaScript can understand, like JSON. And converting any kind of `Object` into JSON is... well, very cumbersome if you won't use any third party framework.

If you're allowed to use third party frameworks, then use a Java JSON library like Gson or Jackson. If you cannot add third party libraries to your code, then you can copy/paste/adapt the basic JSON support for Java located in http://json.org/, it's open source so you can move the java classes in any package of your project and then work with them.

Comment: Thank you! any recomendations of what framework use to convert the collection into a json? Thank you (again)!

Comment: @S.Moreno there are two frameworks mentioned in my answer: Gson and Jackson. Test both and choose the best option for your case.